# How To Write Close All Action For All Documents using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to write close all action for all created documents.  My application has Create and CloseAll menu items. When I create a single document and write some code on that then I click on CloseAll, it asks conformation dialog box "Whether do you want to save or not".

This case is working fine for me. But when I create multiple documents (more than five) and some documents are empty, some documents have text. Then I click on CloseAll menu item, it should ask  conformation dialog box for all documents that have text. But my code is not working in this case. How can I achieve this?

My Working Code:

```
public class CloseAllAction extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ChangeListener {

JTextArea textArea;
JScrollPane scrollpane;
int tabCount=0,doc_count=0;
int i=0;
CloseButtonTabbedPane tabbedPane;
HashSet<String> docSet=new HashSet<>();
boolean update =false;
ArrayList<String> InternalClosing;
private final List<JTextArea> textAreas = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<JScrollPane> scrollPanes = new ArrayList<>();
public CloseAllAction() {

    initComponents();
    tabbedPane=new CloseButtonTabbedPane();
    InternalClosing=new ArrayList<>();
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 512, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 366, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    closeAll = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    create.setText("Create");
    create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(create);

    closeAll.setText("Close All");
    closeAll.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            closeAllActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(closeAll);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 512, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 366, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    textArea=new JTextArea();
    textArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
    scrollpane=new JScrollPane(textArea);
    tabCount++;
    doc_count++;
    String Doc_name="Document "+tabCount;
    boolean value=docSet.add(Doc_name);
    if(value==true) 
        tabbedPane.addTab("Document "+tabCount, null, scrollpane, "Document "+tabCount);
    else{
        tabbedPane.addTab("Document "+doc_count, null, scrollpane, "Document "+doc_count);
        docSet.add("Document "+doc_count);
    }
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(this);
    textAreas.add(textArea);
    scrollPanes.add(scrollpane);
    try {
    tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabCount-1);
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException i){   
    }
    textArea.requestFocus();
    textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(this);
    Document doc=textArea.getDocument();
    doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            int index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
             String sts=tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(index);
                if(!InternalClosing.contains(sts)) {
                    InternalClosing.add(sts);
                    update =true;
                }
             update =true;
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            int index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
             String sts=tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(index);
                if(!InternalClosing.contains(sts)) {
                    InternalClosing.add(sts);
                    update =true;
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
             int index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
             String sts=tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(index);
                if(!InternalClosing.contains(sts)) {
                    InternalClosing.add(sts);
                    update =true;
                }
        }
    });                                    
}                                      

private void closeAllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if( update==false) {
        tabbedPane.removeAll();
        tabCount=0;
        textAreas.clear();
        scrollPanes.clear();
        tabbedPane.tabs.clear();
    }        
    else if(update==true){
        int index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
        String docName=InternalClosing.get(index);
        int totalTabcount=tabbedPane.getTabCount();
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(totalTabcount-1);
        int loop=1;
        while(loop<=totalTabcount) {
            if(!InternalClosing.contains(tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(index)))
            {
                totalTabcount--;
                tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(totalTabcount-1);
            }
            loop++;
        }
        if(InternalClosing.contains(docName))
            {      
                update=false;
                int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                          "Save Changes to this Document", "Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

                int chooserStatus;
                if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    boolean success;
                    String editorString;
                    FileWriter fwriter;
                    PrintWriter outputFile;
                    try{
                        for(int i=0;i<=InternalClosing.size();i++) {
                            index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
                            InternalClosing.remove(docName);
                            if(tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(index).startsWith("Document ")) {
                             Save();
                            }
                           else{
                                String file1=tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
                                DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file1));
                                String line = textAreas.get(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()).getText();
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
                                while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                                    d.writeBytes(line + "\r\n");
                                }
                            }
                            tabbedPane.remove(index);
                            try {
                                textAreas.remove(index);
                                scrollPanes.remove(index);
                                tabCount--;
                           }
                            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException p){ }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e7){       
                        success = false;
                    }
                    success = true;
                    tabbedPane.removeAll();
                }
                else if(reply==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    //I Will Write this
                }
                else if(reply==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                    //I Will Write this
                }
        }   
    }
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseAllAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseAllAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseAllAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseAllAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CloseAllAction().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem closeAll;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
    int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    try {
        textArea=textAreas.get(index);
        scrollpane=scrollPanes.get(index);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e1) {
    }
}

public class CloseButtonTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane
{
    public CloseButtonTabbedPane()
    {
    }
    ArrayList<CloseButtonTab> tabs = new ArrayList<CloseButtonTab>();
    public void addTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component,
            String tip)
    {
        super.addTab(title, icon, component, tip);
        int count = this.getTabCount() - 1;
        CloseButtonTab tab  = new CloseButtonTab(component, title, icon);
        setTabComponentAt(count, tab);
        tabs.add(tab); // Add the new tab to later modify the title
    }
    public void addTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component)
    {
        addTab(title, icon, component, null);
    }
    public void addTab(String title, Component component)
    {
        addTab(title, null, component);
    }
    public class CloseButtonTab extends JPanel
    {
        private Component tab;
        JLabel tabTitle; // Saves the title, modify this label to set a new title
        public CloseButtonTab(final Component tab, String title, Icon icon)
        {
            this.tab = tab;
            setOpaque(false);
            FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 3, 3);
            setLayout(flowLayout);
            setVisible(true);
            tabTitle = new JLabel(title); // Set the tab title
            tabTitle.setIcon(icon);
            add(tabTitle);
            JButton button = new JButton(MetalIconFactory.getInternalFrameCloseIcon(16));
            button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
            button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
            {
                int index;
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
                    tabbedPane.remove(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
                    i--;
                    tabs.remove(index);
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1));
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
                }
            });
            add(button);
        }
    }
}
private void Save() {
    int chooserStatus;
    String filename=null;
    int index=tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    String name=tabbedPane.getTitleAt(index);
        if(name.isEmpty() || name.startsWith("Document ")){
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(450, 400) );
            chooserStatus = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
            if (chooserStatus == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
                File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();            
                if (!selectedFile.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    selectedFile = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
                }
                filename = selectedFile.getPath();
                tabbedPane.tabs.get(index).tabTitle.setText(selectedFile.getName());
                tabbedPane.setToolTipTextAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), filename);
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }      
        boolean success;
        String editorString;
        FileWriter fwriter;
        PrintWriter outputFile;
        try {
            DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
            String line = textAreas.get(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()).getText();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                d.writeBytes(line + "\r\n");
            }
            InternalClosing.remove(filename);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {       
            success = false;
        }
        success = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Why do you set `update=true;` pending on the tool tip text here `String sts = tabbedPane.getToolTipTextAt(index); if (!InternalClosing.contains(sts)) { ...`?

Comment: When create the new Document,It is empty.Whenever add text to Document,Then the update is true and that tool tip text(fileName) is added to the InternalFrameclosing list.

Comment: Please Anybody Check it once.